# Structural break time series

Tags: arima, garch, structural-change

Knowing that tests for structural breaks  deal with breaks
in trend only, under what assumptions do you think it is reasonable to ignore
these breaks when modeling the ARMA process? Can they can affect
ARMA and/or ARCH/GARCH estimation? How?

Answer (score 1):

ARMA/ARCH/GARCH parameter estimates are biased by

1. The magnitude if the change point jumps. Larger jumps will lead to lower estimated AR.
2. The proportion of change points relative to the number of data points. Higher proportion will lead to lower estimated AR.

When these are beyond reasonable depends on the criteria of the individual task. But note that [you can estimate AR(N) parameters while modeling out structural breaks](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/524491/interpolating-data-during-structural-breaks/554165#554165).