# Interpolating data during structural breaks?

Tags: r, structural-change

What is the optimal strategy when you identify a structural break occuring very late in the series? I am using U.S. PCE data and unsurprisingly there is a significant break occuring at the outset of the pandemic. Now according to Pesaran you're supposed to ignore the time interval where the break occurs, taking only a 5-10% pre break and everything after. But there is limited data since it was so recent and my assumption is also that even with 5% it would be very biased towards the pre-break data. My own inclination is to interpolate some data during the break and go from there but I could not find any litterature to justify it and I didn't want to take too many freedoms.

So how should one handle this issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If the structural break only affect a subset of the model parameters, you could use the whole time series to model all other parameters (carrying over info) and only use post-break info to infer the new parameters.

The r pacakge `mcp` can do this. As a simple example, here's a model with an intercept change but with no change in 2nd-order autoregressive coefficients.

```r
# Simulate some AR(2) data with a break at time 130/150 
data = data.frame(
  x = 1:150,
  y = c(rep(10, 130), rep(13, 20)) + arima.sim(list(ar = c(0.7, -0.4)), 150)
)

# Model it as two intercepts with AR(2)
model = list(
  y ~ 1 + ar(2),
  ~ 1
)

# Explore results
fit = mcp(model, data, par_x = "x")
summary(fit)
plot(fit)
predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(x = 200), arma = FALSE)
```

[image]

If you know when the change took place, we can set it rather than inferring it. Just set that value as a prior: `cp_1 = 130`. Unfortunately, the current CRAN version of mcp (v. 0.3.1) has a bug here, so you can approximate it with a very narrow interval:

```r
fit2 = mcp(model, data, par_x = "x", prior = list(cp_1 = "dunif(129.9, 130.1)"))
```